# Check time between two column not working in Php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have table "merchant_slots" and i want to check whether any user going to insert existing time slot or not
,means user should not enter time slot which exist (should not exist between previous "start_time" and "end_time")
So how can i check ?
Here is my table "merchant_slots"

```
id      day     merchantId          start_time          end_time                
1       1           1                   09:00               10:00
2       2           1                   12:00               14:00
3       3           1                   18:00               20:00
```

I tried with following code but not working

```
SELECT *
FROM merchant_slots
WHERE '08:00' > start_time AND end_time < '12:00'
```

Comment: For to check the timeranges overlapping compare start1 with end2 and start2 with end1. If start less than end in each pair then the ranges overlaps.

Comment: @Akina: can you write query so i can check and implement in my side

Comment: '08:00' < end_time && '12:00' > start_time

Comment: @Erik: Can you write "exact" query

Comment: Which part of this concept do you not understand? I'd much rather help you with that so you actually learn something.

Comment: Please complete your [mcve] by explicitly stating your exact desired output.  Please do not mention "insert" if you are executing a SELECT.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that you want to exclude any overlap with existing rows.  If so, you can find the overlaps using:

```
SELECT *
FROM merchant_slots
WHERE end_time > '08:00' AND start_time AND < '12:00'
```

If this returns no rows, then the time span is not being used at all.